# AngularJS - controller properties same instance

Tags: angularjs

I have a checkout in a shop where i have to store a billing and a shipping address. At start the shipping address is the same as the billign address, but the user should be able to change that. If he changes, the shipping address is a copy of the billing address an he can edit it. That works fine, but how i don't know how to handle it, that the shipping address is exactly the same object as the billing address.

Thanks for help!

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

    $scope.billingAddress;

    $scope.shippingAddress;

    $scope.same;

    $scope.setSame = function(value) {
        if (value) {
            $scope.shippingAddress = $scope.billingAddress;
        } else {
            $scope.shippingAddress = angular.copy($scope.billingAddress);
        }
    };

    $scope.setSame(true);
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Are you facing difficulty when the billing and shipping address are same?

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that the call of setSame inside the controller will be executed, but shippingAdress is undefined. After i call the function again shippingAdress is bilingAddress...

Comment: ok i found the solution: If i declare billing and shipping address as an object like `billingAdress = {};` it works fine.